# Need to escape "||" condition from a string

Tags: java, regex, replaceall

I have situation where i need to remove "||" and insert a backslash from a string.

```
String s = "stack||overflow";
```

I need to replace and the resultant string should be "stack\overflow".

I tried using replaceAll function but didn't work.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks,
Sreekanth

Comment: what about using the non `regex` version `String#replace` if you want to do a simple replacement...

Comment: And the point in using `replaceAll` is? Using `replace` instead would be much easier.

Comment: If you have code that doesn't work, and you have a question about it, then **post the code**. That shows that you have made some effort, and it also allows us to see the actual problem that you're having.

Answer (score 2):

This is already described in [Oracle tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/manipstrings.html), part *Replacing Characters and Substrings into a String*:

```
String replace(CharSequence target, CharSequence replacement)
```

> Replaces each substring of this string that matches the literal target sequence with the specified literal replacement sequence.

For example:

```
String s = "stack||overflow.";
System.out.println(s.replace("||","\\"));
```